# $N$ day contract, with a probability of $P$ of extending the contract by K days indefinitely. Probability of the contract lasting $J$ days.

Tags: combinatorics

On any given day there is a likelihood ($P$) of extending the contract a another $K$ days. I know I can expect the contract to last $\frac{N}{1-K\times P}$ days (KP<1), but I have no idea how to calculate the probability of it lasting exactly $J$ days. I attempted turning it into a binary sequence, but the rule prohibiting when the extension can occur (i.e. $J$ could equal 14, but if $N$ is 4 and $K$ is 10, $K$ could not occur after 4 days have passed because the contract would have already ended) is stumping me. Any help appreciated.

Comment: At least J days or exactly J days?  Also, if on day 6, you extend the contract 10 days, what if J = 14?  You didn't *land* on 14.

Comment: It is not OK to expect the contract to last $\frac{N}{1-KP}$ days, if $KP>1$ then it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks Kelvin I clarified. user2661923: "Also, if on day 6, you extend the contract 10 days, what if J = 14? You didn't land on 14". I am looking for the probability of J (in this scenario) equaling numbers of the form N+K*Z, where Z is the number of contract renewals. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the contract lasts for $J$ days. Let $X$ be the number of days where the contract was extended, and $Y$ be the number of days where it was not. Then
$$
X+Y=J\\
X+Y-KX=N
$$
These two equations imply that $X=(J-N)/K$, and $Y=J-(J-N)/K$. This means every outcome lasting $J$ days consists of some ordering of $X+Y$ days, where $X$ of the days are extensions, and $Y$ are not. The total number of ways to choose this ordering is
$$
\binom{X+Y}{X}=\binom{J}{(J-N)/K}
$$
However, not all orderings are valid, in the sense that some of them will cause the contract to end too early. For example, when $N=2, J=5, K=3$, then we get $X=1$ and $Y=4$, for $\binom{5}1$ possible orderings. However, only the orderings $xyyyy$ are valid $yxyyy$; for example $yyxyy$ would mean the contract already ended on day $2$.

It turns out that counting the number of valid arrangements is solved exactly by the generalized ballot problem; see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/252059419_Four_Proofs_of_the_Ballot_Theorem. Using this, the probability of lasting $J$ days exactly is equal to
$$
\frac{N}J\binom{J}{X}P^X(1-P)^{J-X}
$$
where $X=(J-N)/K$.

Comment: Happy to help, this is one of my favorite types of problems!

Comment: I know it's been awhile, but how does this scale in the event you restrict the number of contract extensions? I tried normalizing the results for a max of 5 contract extensions, but am not sure if this is correct.