# Probability of game ending after N dice rolls.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Consider a game where you are given $S$ rolls of a die. On any given roll you may be granted $S$ additional rolls with probability $p$. I was wondering if there was a way to find the probability of getting N total rolls (where N would be a multiple of $S$). Any help appreciated.

I tried looking at all multiples of $S$, considering them strings of length $kS$, where entries are $p$ or $1-p$. The probability is straightforward, but the combinatorics caused me issue. Namely if you end with exactly $S$ rolls, the event with probability $p$ must not have occurred. Another issue is if you ended with $2S$ rolls, $p$ must have occurred exactly once, in the first $S$ rolls (otherwise you wouldn't have gotten the second set of $S$ rolls). The special cases seem to get worse from there.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried looking at all multiples of $S$, considering them strings of length $k*S$, where entries are $p$ or ~$p$. The probability is straightforward, but the combinatorics caused me issue. Namely if you end with exactly $S$ rolls, the event with probability $p$ must not have occurred. Another issue is if you ended with $2S$ rolls, $p$ must have occurred exactly once, in the first $S$ rolls (otherwise you wouldn't have gotten the second set of $S$ rolls). The special cases seem to get worse from there

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905376/n-day-contract-with-a-probability-of-p-of-extending-the-contract-by-k-days)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get $(k+1)S$ total rolls you need to have been granted $k$ extra blocks of $S$ rolls such that for all $0\le i\le k$ at most $i$ blocks are granted in the last $i+1$ blocks, or equivalently at least $k-i$ blocks are granted in the first $k-i$ blocks. The number of ways to assign grants to blocks in this way is the Catalan number $C_k$.

Let $A=(a_1,\dots,a_k,a_{k+1}=0)$ run over all admissible partitions of the $k$ grants across blocks. Then the desired probability $P_{S,p}(k)$ of getting $k$ *total* blocks is
$$P_{S,p}(k+1)=\sum_A\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\binom S{a_i}p^{a_i}(1-p)^{S-a_i}$$
$$=p^k(1-p)^{(k+1)S-k}\sum_A\prod_{i=1}^{k+1}\binom S{a_i}$$
$$=\frac{p^k(1-p)^{(k+1)S-k}}{(S-1)(k+1)+1}\binom{(k+1)S}{k+1}$$
where the last line uses the interpretation of the Fuss–Catalan numbers [A070914](https://oeis.org/A070914).
$$P_{S,p}(k)=\frac{p^{k-1}(1-p)^{kS-k+1}}{kS-k+1}\binom{kS}k$$

Comment: Is this problem still solvable if there were three different probabilities, p1, p2, p3 that could award different amounts of additional rolls : S1,S2, and S3?